# SICP streams in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, sicp, lazy

To brush up on my C++ chops, I've implemented a toy version of ["SICP Streams"](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%25_sec_3.5), which behave like lists with one twist: the first element of the list is always available, the rest of the list is stored as a "promise" to produce the rest of the list.  Calling `rest()` forces its evaluation.

Following is my implementation of the general "EStream" along with a handful of specialized subclasses.  But there are (at least) two areas that need attention:

- Both `head()` and `rest()` return immutable values.  I have yet to get my head around the use of `const` to notify the compiler that this is the case.  Guidance on the use of const (or references to good documentation) would be appreciated.
- As written, the behavior of a stream is split between the `create()` method and the `rest()` method.  I'd like to find a way to restructure things all the logic for the each stream is embodied entirely either in the constructor or the rest() method, if that's possible.

(As an aside, I've created another version of EStream that uses lambdas to defer evaluation of the `rest()` -- it works fine, but it would be nice to not depend on c++11 constructs.  Maybe that's a false concern.)

```
#include <string>


#define NULL_ESTREAM(T) ((EStream<T> *)0)

// (Abstract) Base Class
template <typename T> class EStream {
public:
  virtual T first() = 0;
  virtual EStream<T> *rest() = 0;
};

// ================================================================
// alphabetical below here

// ================
// Return elements of s0 followed by elements of s1
template <typename T> class AppendES : public EStream <T> {
public:

  static EStream<T> *create( EStream <T> *s0, EStream <T> *s1 ) {
    return (s0 == NULL_ESTREAM(T)) ? s1 : new AppendES<T>(s0, s1);
  }

  T first() {
    return s0_->first(); 
  }

  EStream<T> *rest() { 
    return AppendES::create(s0_->rest(), s1_);
  }

protected:
  AppendES( EStream<T> *s0, EStream<T> *s1) : s0_(s0), s1_(s1) {}
  EStream<T> *s0_;
  EStream<T> *s1_;
};

// ================
// Generate a stream of constant values
template <typename T> class ConstantES : public EStream <T> {
public:
  static ConstantES<T> *create(T value) { return new ConstantES<T>(value); }
  T first() { return value_; }
  ConstantES<T> *rest() { return this; }
protected:
  ConstantES(T value): value_ (value) {};
  T value_;
};

// ================
// Restart stream s when it is exhausted
template <typename T> class CycleES : public EStream <T> {
public:

  static EStream<T> *create( EStream <T> *s ) {
    return (s == NULL_ESTREAM(T)) ? s : new CycleES(s, s);
  }

  T first() {
    return s_->first(); 
  }

  EStream<T> *rest() { 
    EStream<T> *t = s_->rest();
    if (t == NULL_ESTREAM(T)) {
      return new CycleES(s_head_, s_head_);
    } else {
      return new CycleES(t, s_head_);
    }
  }

protected:
  CycleES( EStream<T> *s, EStream<T> *s_head) : s_(s), s_head_(s_head) {}
  EStream<T> *s_;
  EStream<T> *s_head_;
};

// ================
// Drop the first n elements of a stream
template <typename T> class DropES : public EStream <T> {
public:

  static EStream<T> *create( EStream <T> *s, int n) {
    while ((n > 0) && (s != NULL_ESTREAM(T))) {
      n -= 1;
      s = s->rest();
    }
    return s;
  }

  // these should never get called.
  T first() { return (T)0; }
  EStream<T> *rest() { return NULL_ESTREAM(T); }

protected:
  DropES() {}
};

// ================
// Generate a stream of integers, counting up from a starting value
class IntegerES : public EStream<int> {
public:
  static IntegerES *create(int initial) { return new IntegerES(initial); }
  int first() { return value_; }
  IntegerES *rest() { return IntegerES::create(value_ + 1); }
protected:
  IntegerES(int initial): value_ (initial) {}
  int value_;
};

// ================
// Return elements of s0, then s1, then s0.  If either stream is
// empty, emit the other stream.
template <typename T> class InterleaveES : public EStream <T> {
public:

  static EStream<T> *create( EStream <T> *s0, EStream <T> *s1 ) {
    return (s0 == NULL_ESTREAM(T)) ? s1 : new InterleaveES<T>(s0, s1);
  }

  T first() {
    return s0_->first(); 
  }

  EStream<T> *rest() { 
    return InterleaveES::create(s1_, s0_->rest());
  }

protected:
  InterleaveES( EStream<T> *s0, EStream<T> *s1) : s0_(s0), s1_(s1) {}
  EStream<T> *s0_;
  EStream<T> *s1_;
};

// ================
// Return the first n elements of a stream
template <typename T> class TakeES : public EStream <T> {
public:
  static EStream<T> *create(EStream<T> *s, int n) {
    return ((n <= 0) || (s == NULL_ESTREAM(T))) ? NULL_ESTREAM(T) : new TakeES<T>(s, n);
  }
  T first() { 
      return s_->first();
  }
  EStream<T> *rest() {
    return TakeES::create(s_->rest(), n_ - 1);
  }
protected:
  TakeES(EStream<T> *s, int n): s_ (s), n_ (n) {}

  EStream<T> *s_;
  int n_;
};
```

Comment: Why the ugly `NULL_ESTREAM` macro when [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) exists?

Answer (score 3):

Obvois catch: make your destructor virtual! The fact you do not have explicit destructor does not imply you have no destructor at all.

C++11 is widely supported these days. It provides useful tools to boost your productivity and to make code clearer. I see no reason not to use in little personal projects with no legacy or wierd constraints.

On the code itself:

My main concern is usage of pointers. Do you really need run-time polimorphism here?

In case you don't, make create functions constructors and provide additional template parameters for underling streams, like:

```
template <typename T, typename ES> class TakeES{
public:
  TakeES(ES s, int n) {    
    n_ = n;
    s_ = s; 
  }
  T first() { 
      return s_.first();
  }
  TakeES rest() {
    return TakeES(s_.rest(), n_ - 1);
  }
  bool is_null() {
    return s_.is_null() || n_ < 1;
  }
protected:
  ES s_;
  int n_;
};
```

Acutually, you can go further, and make these streams compatible with stl iterators.

On the other hand, if you do want runtime polimorphism, you still need some tweaks to be made:

- Constructors are still better then create functions, because user can deside allocation scheme for streams.
- Plain pointers say nothing about ownage. When function takes plain pointer it usually means it will not try to own it (save for future use). right now we can easily trigger a leak:

  `auto stream = CyclesES<int>::create(IntegerES::create(42));`

Take `unique_ptr<EStream<T>>` to communicate you are fully responsible for a life time of consumed stream.

A note about DropES. The fact it's functions should not be called means it is not a stream, so it should not inherit from it. Make it just a function. This will save a lot of headackes from users with `T`'s not convertible from `0`, etc.